# Select one distinct row based on a case statement applied to a column

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm unable to figure out a sql query (using MS Sql Server). I'm trying to retrieve a single row from a dataset in which an item with one id can have more than one row. The part that is throwing me off is that the correct row should be based on a "hierarchy". I have trying to throw a case statement at the problem.

Some sample data:

```
Id           Class       Date
100          Red         2012-12-12
100          Blue        2012-12-31
200          Red         2012-10-31
300          Green       2012-04-04
300          Blue        2011-09-01
```

I want to return a single row based on the value of Class.

```
Case When Red Then
    Date 
Case When Blue Then 
    Date
Case When Green Then 
    Date 
Else
    ''
```

My final dataset should look like this:

```
Id           Class       Date
100          Red         2012-12-12
200          Red         2012-10-31
300          Blue        2011-09-01
```

So, if one of the duplicate rows has a value of Red, use the date from that row first. Then blue, then green.

Been working on this one all day, playing around with subqueries, group bys, havings, case statements, derived tables. I'm quite rusty on my sql skills, as it's been a while.

Any hints on the direction I should take?

Comment: How many classes are there? Can they be hard-coded?

Comment: Is there a function that can convert the "Red" "Blue" "Green" to a number (which can act as a priority? Something like "CASE CLASS WHEN 'Red' then 1 WHEN 'Blue' then 2 ELSE 3 END"
If so, you should be ablbe to select the top priority, using a nested query.

Comment: There probably about 100 different possible class values, but Red, Blue and Green are the ones I want. They can be hard coded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this

```
;WITH cte AS
  (
    SELECT Id, Class, Date,
      row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY Id
                         ORDER BY CASE Class
                                  WHEN 'Red' THEN 1
                                  WHEN 'Blue' THEN 2
                                  WHEN 'Green' THEN 3
                                  ELSE 4 END) as rn
    FROM MyTable
   )

SELECT Id, Class, Date
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: I made a few tweaks and this appears to be what I need. I'm not familiar with the row_number function, but it has been proven to be quite useful. I'll do some more testing to verify my results. I'll accept the answer once I verify the results. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select id, class, date
  from TABLE
 where class = COLOR
   and date  = (select min(date) from TABLE where class = COLOR)
```

Answer (score 0):

I like @bobs query and it'll work well on a TSQL database.

This is just another way of doing the same thing that may be a little more portable to other SQL databases that have common table expressions but not the same row number syntax;

```
;WITH cte AS
(SELECT *, CASE Class WHEN 'Red' THEN 1 WHEN 'Blue' THEN 2
                      WHEN 'Green' THEN 3 ELSE 4 END c FROM myTable)

SELECT b1.Id, b1.Class, b1.Date
FROM cte b1 
LEFT JOIN cte b2 
  ON b1.Id = b2.Id AND b1.c > b2.c
WHERE b2.Class IS NULL
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6c5cc/1).